# How to imitate ActionBar menu?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-actionbar, widget

Is possible create something like this without using ActionBar? I just need "button" which will rolling some items after click...
[image]

Comment: Depending on your SDK level, you could use: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html

Comment: Unfortunately my SDK level starts on 8 :(

Comment: Have you considered http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: Also consider http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html which you can fill with whatever view you want its API level 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActionBarSherlock might be useful in your case: http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: Hi, I implemented ActionBarSherlock and it works on Android ICS like a classic ActionBar, but on Android 2.3 there is missing this button with menu...is it standard behavior of ActionBarSherlock?

Comment: No. You can do many of the same things with ActionBarSherlock as you can do with a regular ActionBar, and the overflow menu is one of them.

Comment: Ok, sounds good, but what I do wrong? I see overflow menu only on ICS, on 2.3 is still nothing...any idea?

Answer (score 1):

A "dirty" method would be to link your button to an invisible Spinner, which will become visible as soon as the button is pressed. Then it's simply a case of binding the onSelect event of the spinner and theming it.